# Ansible / Jinja datetime parsing issue

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a following ansible playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ host | default('host') }}"
  remote_user: user

  tasks:
  - name: set date 2
    set_fact:
      datetime_2: "Wed 2023-09-06 18:14:07 CEST"

  - name: parse date 2
    set_fact:
      parsed_datetime_2: "{{ datetime_2 | to_datetime('%a %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z') }}"

  - name: print
    debug:
      msg: "{{ parsed_datetime_2 }}"
```

And getting error:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value ({'parsed_datetime_2': \"{{ datetime_2 | to_datetime('%a %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z') }}\"}), and could not be converted to an dict.The error was: time data 'Wed 2023-09-06 18:14:07 CEST' does not match format '%a %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'
The error appears to be in '/home/ai/git/provisioning/ansible/ai-datetime-test.yml': line 9, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: parse date 2\n    ^ here\n"}
```

Is there a bug in ansible or jinja?

Version info:

```
ansible [core 2.15.2]
  python version = 3.10.12 (main, Jun 11 2023, 05:26:28) [GCC 11.4.0] (/usr/bin/python3)
  jinja version = 3.0.3
```

Comment: What's the output of `echo $LC_TIME` on your controller? The above runs like a charm if I `export LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8` on my side but gave the exact same error as it was by default `fr_FR.UTF-8` hence the abbreviated day of the week at start wasn't recognized (i.e. in that case it should be `mer.` instead of `Wed`)

Comment: You can check what format is expected in the current locale using current datetime by debugging the expression `"{{ '%a %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z' | strftime }}"`

Comment: @Zeitounator, yes, locale is the problem, thank you so much for help!